# Trying to identify a SF novel in which humans capture some creatures for sport but in neutrino universe there are intelligent beings

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to identify a SF novel that I read about 35 years ago. It was in Turkish but was translated from another language, probably English.

Humans capture some creatures for sport in space. These creatures gives off different colors. Most prized color was red because it is very seldom found. Protagonist believes these are intelligent beings and with some mechanism passes into a different universe related with neutrinos. In this parallel neutrino universe there are intelligent beings and communicated to the protagonist with telepathy. They told those colors are based on age of creature, red meaning more than hundred years old, elders of their society. Protagonist somehow returned to our universe and saved those creatures from further hunting.

At one point in the novel, the great great grand parent of the protagonist is said to have been a king's pirate ('privateer') during the Age of Sail.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Did they specifically refer to it as the *"neutrino universe"*?

Comment: I read it about 35 years ago from a turkish translation. I don't remember the cover. It mentioned neutrinos and different universe so as shortcut i said neutrino universe.

Comment: I wonder if you aren't remembering  _Flux_ by Stephen Baxter.

Comment: Thanks Spencer but it is not Flux.

Comment: I found it. It was turkish translation of Les Whums Se Vengent written by Louis Thirion